# How to UPDATE from within an INSERT trigger in MySQL? What other approach can I take?

Tags: mysql

I've the following trigger which is really bugging me.

I want to do an UPDATE inside the trigger, but MySQL doesn't allow it, since the statement "triggering" the trigger refer to the participants table.

What can I do in order to make it work? I've considered stored procedures, but they are also forbidden in this case.

**The logic is**: I've a table with participants in a meeting. The invariant that people from the 'tap' group should always accept the invitation if someone from the 'vip' group is attending. In this case, if a 'vip' is attending the meeting I must **UPDATE** all 'tap' attendances, but how is this possible???

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER tap_meet_vip
BEFORE INSERT ON participants
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.pid IN (SELECT userid FROM people WHERE `group` = 'vip')) THEN  # new participant is a member of the vip group
        UPDATE participants SET `status` = 'a' WHERE pid IN (SELECT userid FROM people WHERE `group` = 'tap') AND meetid = NEW.meetid ; # update status to `accept` of all tap group participants   
    ELSEIF (NEW.pid IN (SELECT userid FROM people WHERE `group` = 'tap') AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM participants INNER JOIN people ON pid = userid WHERE `group` = 'vip')) THEN # new participant is a member of the tap group and meeting has vip participant
        SET NEW.`status` = 'a';
    END IF;
END;$$
```

The above is written using MySQL and the version is 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can't do all this in a trigger. Trigger is already locked the table so update statement can't get the lock. According to the [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html):

> Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger

So you can create a stored procedure, that inserts into/Updates the target table, then updates the other row(s), all in a transaction. With a stored proc you'll manually commit the changes (insert and update).

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXIST marks;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE marks(IN marks INT)
BEGIN 
     INSERT INTO first VALUES(marks);
END $$
DELIMITER ;

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO first VALUES (16);
CALL marks(18);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Could you give an example of your suggestion?

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely try it. Are you sure the approach work? Seems like a hack?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen This is typical way to do that

Comment: But using a procedure why can't the same problems occur that MySQL tries to avoid by not allowing the UPDATE in INSERT trigger?

Comment: In trigger, it was single statement in single trasaction but here, its two differ statement in single transaction.